# Foo element not found in jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js

Tags: javascript, carousel, caroufredsel

I got issue with **foo element** which is not found in carouFredSel. 
that's why some of items don't work on my page. even if I use **jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js** is still same issue. 
Is there anyone who knows how to solve this foo element ?

> carouFredSel: No element found for "#foo".
>
> carouFredSel: No element found for "#foo2".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing carouFredSel on an element that cannot be found, it's not an issue with carouFredSel but with your code.

See the source code of carouFredSel: https://github.com/gilbitron/carouFredSel/blob/master/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js#L31

Check the documentation for basic usage: http://docs.dev7studios.com/article/23-getting-started-with-the-caroufredsel-jquery-plugin

If you want to find the code responsible for this error, search your files for `$("#foo").carouFredSel`

Comment: Ok I got it, but I don't know how to solve it, I found #foo and #foo2 in my js fle function.js